# How do I make a EPG in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm about to build a EPG in silverlight.

What controls would you recommend for that?

As I see it there are three sections:
 1. Channels  -- section should only scroll up and down.
 2. Time -- should only scroll sideways.
 3. Programs -- should scroll in all directions

I would love some suggestions on how to build the xaml.

Comment: I assume you mean a programming guide?  How will your user be navigating this guide?  Is it designed for a mouse or will it be touch controlled?  Will navigation with a remote control be necessary?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to call it =)
Touch for the Windows Phone 7 but I'm considering makeing a Silverlight version for the web also (so mouse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any pre-built controls in the SDK that are perfect for a "classic" EPG

I'd recommend you:

- look at how the WP7 Calendar app looks and feels - they use gestures to enable you to scroll through times - e.g. in the month view.
- consider whether you want to support both Portrait and Landscape view - if you do want to keep a left-hand column constantly visible then Landscape might be more usable.
- build an early prototype using "standard" Pivot and ListBox controls - then look at building a custom-built control as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but the Panorama and ListBox controls should get you started.

Comment: The problem is that the channel and time column/row should be frozen so it is always shown regardless how I scroll/pan in the program section.